# How to get the other application data in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application i have a share option. when i clicked on that will show a list of applications, If i selected on of the application then that application will be stated.
Now from that application if user select share and touch my app icon then that shared information needs to be shown in my activity is this scenario possible in android? if possible what is the best of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three easy lessons: [Sharing Content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html).

Comment: thanks for quick response i will read it.